# convert mtime to to human-readable date

Tags: python, timestamps, time

I have different `mtime` values, and I am trying to convert them to human-readable date. I am triyng to achieve this using python:

```py
import time

t = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(1491613200000))

print(t) #returns something strange '49237-05-04 19:00:00'
```

My first thought was that the value for `mtime` was not good, but I had tested it using https://www.epochconverter.com/, and it was converted to a human-readable date format:

[image]

If I am using `time.time()` (which returns the current time in seconds since the Epoch) then I also have a human-readable date:

```
import time
t = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(time.time()))
print(t)# returns '2020-02-20 02:18:42'
```

What am I missing when doing the conversion ? Thank you.

Comment: Note the *"Assuming that this timestamp is in **milliseconds**"* in the epochconverter output - AFAIK, python's `time.localime` assumes it is in **seconds**. Try dividing your timestamp value by 1000.

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver , you are right.